# How to use dplyr to subset dataframe based on group_by in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that consists of sales and population data. Reference below:

```
Location Sales Population Month
A         10       480     Jan
B         12       480     Jan
C         14       480     Jan 
A         13       480     Jan
B         11       480     Jan
C         16       480     Jan
A         12       480     Jan
B         10       480     Jan
C         14       480     Jan
```

What I would like to do is use dplyr to group by month (only showing Janurary but goes to Dec) for sum of sales and the month's population.

I get the sales with this line of code by my population comes out as NA..

```
test2 <- df_2019 %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarize(SumSales = sum(Total_Sales, na.rm = TRUE), Pop_Sum = sum(Population, na.rm = TRUE))

Month
SumSales
Pop_Sum
1   Apr 285591.9    134786490
2   Aug 384246.5    131901771
3   Dec 254748.9    89512147
4   Feb 251463.7    135634878
5   Jan 243624.6    135901304
6   Jul 286468.8    134335668
7   Jun 283395.2    134335668
8   Mar 289453.8    135658132
9   May 365272.2    134768586
10  Nov 291248.8    89576444
11  Oct 375402.2    89589288
12  Sep 290888.5    132878020
```

DESIRED OUTPUT would look like this:

```
Month
SumSales
Pop_Sum
1   Apr 285591.9    437
2   Aug 384246.5    440
3   Dec 254748.9    443
4   Feb 251463.7    435
5   Jan 243624.6    480
6   Jul 286468.8    455
7   Jun 283395.2    465
8   Mar 289453.8    460
9   May 365272.2    479
10  Nov 291248.8    435
11  Oct 375402.2    444
12  Sep 290888.5    451
```

Where Month Population has mutliple rows with the same value but sales are unique. Any help would be very helpful!

Comment: Try `df_2019 %>%
  group_by(Location, Month) %>%
  summarize(SumSales = sum(Sales, na.rm = TRUE), Pop_Sum = sum(Population, na.rm = TRUE))` . Alternately, you can also use `summarize_at`, `df_2019 %>%
  group_by(Location, Month) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(Sales, Population), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
`

Comment: This is a great start - got population values but it sums all the population values instead of just taking the Months assocaited value (the total popuilation is already calculated).

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear @RonakShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `population` values are already calculated we can take any `population` value for each month. For example, taking the 1st value of `Population`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)

df_2019 %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  summarize(SumSales = sum(Total_Sales, na.rm = TRUE), 
            Pop_Sum = first(Population))
```

Comment: Brilliant - Thank you